# Unit Testing a method that calls a stored procedure and returns the results

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a question about unit testing.  I have a method that takes in 2 date time parameters : start time, and end time.  The method calls a database and returns a set of records between the the 2 date times.  I have been told to unit test this logic, but I am not sure how.  My first try was to directly call the database and qry the table in question.  Then call the method.  Lastly I would compare the 2 results and see if they are the same.
It does not make sense to me to test this method because all of the logic is in the database.  I could moq a few basic objects, but then all I would be testing would be if my fake data is returned.  i.e. pass in x, get back y, results not null would pass.  I might be on the wrong track here so I could use some advice please.

Comment: Hard to help without an ounce of code. Please post the code of the method that calls the stored procedure.

Comment: _"I have been told to unit test this logic"_ - why don't you ask the person who told you to clarify what they want?

Answer (score 1):

If you have logic in your database that you want to unit test, then unfortunately, you only really have three options:

1. Extract the logic into a service and unit test that (this has the consequence of a potentially large quantity of rework)
2. Call the procedure in the unit test inside a transaction and rollback (this has the drawback that you are dependant on a database existing and slows down your unit tests)
3. SQL Server has a facility to use [shared classes inside its stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) - so you can unit test that code in isolation.

I've previously [written](http://pmichaels.net/2017/02/04/designing-debugging-database-unit-tests/) on this subject, so you might find that useful.

Comment: --#1 -- unfortunately this is the WCF service that is being called to return the data, so for this situation it would not work, but normally I agree with this.  --#2 -- this is what I am currently doing, but was called out on it because of bad practice.  --#3-- we have a DB team that does not allow for us to touch the db, only make use of it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean - a WCF service can contain logic in the same way as any other service can

Comment: so there is a front end web site that calls this service.  I am updating logic in an existing WCF service.  All data is called from the web site though service layers.  The service layers hit the database directly.

Comment: -- nice article: http://pmichaels.net/2017/02/04/designing-debugging-database-unit-tests/

Comment: Then you need a simply abstraction layer inbetween the service and the DB.  I would also challenge that unit testing a DB is "bad practice".  It's not ideal, but it's better than not having the test at all

Comment: That's why I asked for the OP to post some code at least. Without anything to see, we are guessing here.

Comment: I agree testing database is "bad **", especially when the logic I am testing is self contained in a stored procedure.  This should be up to the data base team to verify that their procedure is working correctly, not the developer interacting with their results.

Comment: @Juan - the code you are requesting is exactly what I described.  Pass in 2 parms, using ado.net call stored procedure, return the results. Nothing else.  There is no manipulation of data or results.  This method is a direct call to the db.

Comment: @pm_2 -- Then you need a simply abstraction layer inbetween the service and the DB -- I can work with this.. thanks